# Increase space table rows, but don't increase the space in the inner tabulars

Tags: tables

I have a document where I want the rows of the table further apart. However, there is also an inner part where I used the tabular. like this:

```
\begin{table}[!htb]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{c c}
         cell 1 & cell 2\\
         \begin{tabular} cell 3.1 \\ cell 3.2 \end{tabular} & cell 4\\
    \end{tabular}
end{table}
```

However, if I do something like add: `\def\arraystretch{1.5}` The distance between cells 1,2 and 3,4 increases, but so does the distance between cells 3.1 and 3.2.

So, how does one edit the rowdistance between cells 1,2 and 3,4 without changing the distance between rows 3.1 and 3.2?

Comment: unrelated to the row spacing but why `[!htb]` ? (not allowing p makes going to the end of the document more likely and `!` is only for special case)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `cellspace` package:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[column=0]{cellspace}
\setlength\cellspacetoplimit{6pt}
\setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{\cellspacetoplimit}


\begin{document}

\begin{table}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{0c 0c}
         cell 1 & cell 2\\
         \begin{tabular}{cc} cell 3.1 \\ cell 3.2 \end{tabular} & cell 4\\
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Great, thank you. However, this does not seem to work when the first character of cell 3.1 is a W (the first character drops for some reason). Fixed that by changing the first character to eW. The first character drops, so that becomes a W. But does anyone know why just a W does not work?

Comment: @Michiel: The code accidentially worked. Actually, the "inner" `tabular` was missing the column specifiers. I did not spot that in your original code but I have now updated my answer with the corrected version. You can of course also select different columns specifiers such as `l` or `r` if you don't want the contents of the inner tabular to be horizontally centered.

Comment: If you want all contents in the first column of the outer table to be left aligned and also want the left column of the inner tabular to also be left aligned with the other cells, you might want to use `\begin{tabular}{@{}ll@{}}` for the inner tabular.